# javascript how to determine if a string character at given position is wrapped by parentheses

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to check if a string character at given position is wrapped by parentheses? That is to say not using this:

```js
                const string = "I hope to see a living Tasmanian wolf (thylacine)";
                
                function isWrapped(pos) {
                    return string.slice(0, pos).split('').reverse().join().indexOf('(') !== -1 && string.slice(pos + 1).indexOf(')') !== -1;
                }

                console.log(isWrapped(40));
                console.log(isWrapped(4));
```

since my solution needs to substring the string into two strings from the position and then split the first part into array, reverse it and joining it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expression

```js
var regExp = /\(([^)]+)\)/;
var string = "I hope to see a living Tasmanian wolf (thylacine)"
var matches = regExp.exec(string);

//matches[1] contains the value between the parentheses
console.log(string.indexOf(matches[1]));
```

You can wrap it in a function

```js
function checkPos(str, pos){
  
  


var regExp = /\(([^)]+)\)/;

var matches = regExp.exec(str);

//matches[1] contains the value between the parentheses
if(str.indexOf(matches[1]) == pos){
  return true
}else return false

}
var string = "I hope to see a  living Tasmanian wolf (thylacine)"

console.log(checkPos(string, 40))
```

Comment: if I pass 4 your function returns -1 and if pass 40 returns -1 as well... how does it work?